# $TM/ D$ is trivial if and only if there is an $1$-form $\alpha$ such that $D = \text{Ker }\alpha$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $ D$ a distribution of dimension $n-1$. I'm trying to prove that $D$ is coorientable (*i.e.* the bundle $TM/D = \sqcup_{x \in M} T_xM/D_x$ has a global trivialization) if and only if $D$ is the kernel of a non-vanishing $1$-form $\alpha$.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

$\Leftarrow$ Let us suppose that $D = \text{Ker }\alpha = \bigsqcup_{x \in M}\text{Ker }\alpha(x)$. We will construct a global trivialization $\phi$ from $\alpha$. Since $\alpha(x):T_xM \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is surjective (as $\alpha$ is non-vanishing), $\overline{\alpha(x)}:T_xM/\text{Ker }\alpha(x) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ in a linear iso. Let us define
$$\phi: TM/D \rightarrow M \times \mathbb R:(x, [X_x]) \mapsto (x, \overline{\alpha(x)}([X_x])).$$
We clearly see that $\pi_1 \circ \phi = \pi$ (where $\pi_1: M\times \mathbb R \rightarrow M$ is the projection on the first component and $\pi:TM/D \rightarrow M$ is the projection bundle of $TM/D$). Here it only remain to show that $\phi$ is a diffeo, here is my first question, see below. (1)

$\Rightarrow$ Since there exists a global trivialization
$$\phi: TM/D \rightarrow M \times \mathbb R:(x, [X_x]) \mapsto (x, \phi_x([X_x])),$$
we can define $\alpha(x)(X_x) =  \phi_x([X_x])$. We just have to prove that $\alpha$ is an $1$-form and that $D = \text{Ker }\alpha$. First, since $\phi$ is a trivialization, $\phi_x$ is a linear iso therefore $\alpha(x)$ is a linear functionnal on $T_xM$. Moreover it is clear that $\text{Ker }\alpha(x) = D_x$ because $\phi_x$ is an iso, hence the only vectors that are send to zero are the ones in $D_x$. Now we have to prove that $\alpha$ is a smooth section of $M$. We have that $(\pi' \circ \alpha)(x) = \pi'(\phi_x) = x$. Here is my second question (2).

**QUESTIONS:**

Here are my questions:

(1): I really do not see how to show that it is a diffeo. I even have some difficulties to show that $\phi$ is a smooth function. If both component of $\phi$ are smooth we are good but how can I show that $\overline{\alpha}$ is smooth in $x$ from the fact that $\alpha$ is ?

(2): Here is a bit the same question as above, how can I show that $\alpha:M \rightarrow T^*M$ is smooth from the fact that $\phi_x$ is ?

Is this a right way to show this equivalence ? It seems to work but I have some difficulties with details..

English is not my mother tongue, so there must be a lot of mistakes, sorry for that.

Comment: It seems like you need to spend a little time thinking about how to describe the smooth structure on $TM/D$. Maybe start by asking yourself: "why is this vector bundle a smooth manifold?"

Answer (score 1):

Let's cheat: fix a Riemannian metric ${\tt g}$ for $M$, so that $TM/\mathcal{D} \cong \mathcal{D}^\perp$.

Assume that $\mathcal{D} = \ker \alpha$ for non-vanishing $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$. Use ${\tt g}$ to convert $\alpha$ to a non-vanishing vector field $\alpha^\sharp \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, normal to $\mathcal{D}$ --- then $\alpha^\sharp \in \Gamma(\mathcal{D}^\perp)$ gives the global trivialization $\Phi\colon M \times \Bbb R \to \mathcal{D}^\perp$ by $\Phi(x,\lambda) = \lambda \alpha^\sharp_x$.

Conversely, assume that $\Phi\colon M\times \Bbb R \to \mathcal{D}^\perp$ is a given global trivialization for $\mathcal{D}^\perp$. Define a vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ by $X_x = \Phi(x,1)$, and note that $X$ never vanishes. In particular, $X \in \Gamma(\mathcal{D}^\perp)$. Then use ${\tt g}$ to convert $X$ to a non-vanishing $1$-form $\alpha = X_\flat \in \Omega^1(M)$. Clearly $\mathcal{D} = \ker \alpha$.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have any background in Riemannian Geometry, how can I show that $TM/D = D^\perp$ ?